# What Minigames are available for Final Fantasy XIII-2

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

Minigames have appeared in past Final Fantasy games and did a number of different things. Some were just something fun or time consuming to do, some gave rare items, and others progressed the story.

What minigames (event games, subgames) are available to play/participate in Final Fantasy XIII-2 and what do you get for completing them?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. Can you be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish in the game?

Comment: @downvoters Other than Mark Trapp (who I am assuming was the first) what is your complaint on my question? I have edited it to be more specific. This should have one and only one answer.

Comment: It probably would've been better to ask a new question than to rewrite this one after it attracted an answer: now the answer provided doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Rolled back. Was trying to salvage the question. But I still stand that this can be answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far I've seen chocobo racing, a really terrible slot machine game, a quiz game (called Brain Blast), and puzzle mini games (Temporal Rifts). There are references to a card game that will be released through future DLC as well. You can get fragments for completing the quizzes and Temporal Rifts, and fragments and coins for doing well enough at slots and racing.